# bis.available() возвращает ноль, не получается скачать байтовый массив данных из сети

Tags: java, lan

Пытаюсь скачать песню из интернета.

`urlcon.getContentLength()` возвращает размер моего файла, это для проверки соединения и размера.

Почему `bis.available()` возвращает ноль почему? и почему не идет запись? почему не получается скачать байтовый массив?

```
 if (musicDirectory.exists()) {
        File file = new File(musicDirectory, name);
        try {
            URLConnection urlcon = urls.openConnection();
            System.out.println(urlcon.getContentLength());
            InputStream is = urlcon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(file));
            int size = bis.available();
            System.out.println(size);
            while (bis.available() > 0) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                bis.read(buffer, 0, bis.available());
                bos.write(buffer, 0, bis.available());
            }
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory not found");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде есть ошибка. Нужно так:

```
while ((count = bis.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    bos.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Можно короче записать:

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/information.asp");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Тут еще варианты [загрузки файла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

И вот так лучше не писать:

```
if (musicDirectory.exists()) {
    //...
} else {
    try {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory not found");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо). а можете подсказать что я не так сделал?

Comment: добавил исправление для вашего кода